# ASP: Get the value from javascript using getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am trying to get value from javascript using getElementbyId but i am not getting it.

If i put,

```
<input type="text" id="disprice<% =pID %>" value="<%=disprice%>" name="Price" />
```

like this then i am getting value from java script in my text box.

But if i try to get that same thing like this,

```
<span class="productListPrice" id="disprice<% =pID %>">
```

then i am not getting the value..

Please help me if possible.

Mitesh

Comment: Could please use the `101 010` icon in the editor to format your code? I think some of it might have been lost? Also, you're missing `id="Price"` for `getElementById` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your texbox needs an id.

More details http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_getelementbyid

Answer (score 0):

@mitesh: Here's some sample code that should help --

JavaScript:

```
var price = document.getElementById('Price');
```

ASP:

```
Dim iPrice
iPrice = Request.Form("Price")
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="Price" name="Price" value="<%=iPrice %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Only `input` values are transmitted back to the server on a postback and the `name` is used (not the `id`). The id is primarily for doing things in JavaScript client-side.

Also, in both cases, `getElementById` will return the element with the given id. However, the element itself is different (a span as no inherent `value`). This step may require some more troubleshooting to determine "what" isn't working.